# Find the farthest node in an unordered graph

Tags: graph, tree, distance

this is not an homework, i'd like to find in an unordered graph ( a cloud of points connected all each ohter ) the farthest point , or the most isolated node. This is how i have solved the problem, i have computed the distance matrix for all nodes and for each one i accumulate the distance ( sum for each row ) , this gives me a measure of how much the node is distant from all the others.
Then i search for the maximum.
I don't know if this sounds correct, how can i solve this problem in a time less than O( n^2 ) ???

Answer (score 0):

If your definition  of farthest point involves the distance between a node and all the other nodes, you will have a hard time doing so without calculating all the distances between the point `(n*(n-1)/2)`